# HTML5 video play button not showing on iOS iPad

Tags: ios, html, ipad, video

I have a HTML5 video that has a play button rendered by Safari on the iPhone but I can't figure out why it's not appearing on the iPad.

I took a look at Streamable and Gfycat and they both have a play button on their html5 videos.

I do not want to render the controls attribute of the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to show using this script.

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) && (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)!= null)){

        $('video').prop("controls",true);
    }
```